# Get reference for current class

Tags: java, class, oop, this

maybe it is trivial question, but is there some way in Java how to get current class reference? Something like `this` for class, not for object? Eg. in static method I need to refer to current class, how can I get it?:

```
public class Test {
    public static void test(){
        this.getClass(); // not working, can not use this to return class object Test
    }
}
```

To more specify my question:

Is something in JAVA like `this` for current class, or do I have to use `ClassName.class`, even if I am inside some class, to get this class reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the class literal as follows -

```
Test.class
```

Comment: Yes I know about this format but I don't want to use class name. Just to point to current class.

Comment: Because I was curious if there is any other way to do it, to not need to type different code for different classes.

Comment: FAIK, this is the best way. You can use reflection,  but you would have provide the fully qualified class name as a string, which is even worse.

Comment: OK, so nothing like `this` exists for current class, I have to use `ClassName.class`, even if I am inside some class, to get this class reference.

Comment: That's correct, unless you want to do something like `Class.forName("pkg.Test")`, which is a lot worser than just doing `Test.class`.

Comment: what the op want is the equivalent of ```__PACKAGE__``` in perl.

Answer (score 3):

`static` method cannot have `this` reference, static method is associated with class state.

You can use `Test.class`.